# Delete all folders in specified path that do not have word "edit" in them?

Tags: command-line, find, rm, delete

I'm trying to set up a simple script that would clean up my `working folder`.
The `working folder` is structured like that:

```
Project 1
Project 1 [edited]
Project 2
Project 2 [edited]
Project 3
Project 3 [edited]
...
```

All project folders contain only files. The objective is to get rid of all folders within `working folder` that do ***not*** have `[edited]` in name.

Comment: What did you try and where is it not working? Are there any error messages?

Comment: @Den: (1) You may get more help if you show the *actual* command(s) that you tried rather than just saying that you tried something. (2) If you have a directory called `balance`, and it contains a directory called `credit` (note: contains “`edit`”), and ***it*** contains a directory called `debt`, what should happen? Should `debt` be deleted (even though it’s contained within `credit`)? Should `balance` be deleted (even though it ***contains*** the `credit` subdirectory)? … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: (3) Don’t try that ``rm -irf`` command.  At least in my copy of `rm`, the order of the options matters (I believe that this is a violation of some rule or standard) — if the `f` comes last, it overrides the `i`.  Better use `rm -rfi` instead.  (4) @Theophrastus: Note that your approach will delete a top-level directory even if it contains a subdirectory called `*edit*`.  I have asked the OP how that case should be handled.

Comment: I have edited my question to include more details with precise folder structure

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica', well the [standard says](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/rm.html) "-f
Do not prompt for confirmation. [...] Any previous occurrences of the -i option shall be ignored." so it seems to imply that the order could matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU find, something like

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1  ! -name "*edit*"
```

should match the files in the current directory that don't have "edit" in their names, and print the names. Of course you could add e.g. `-type d -iname "*project*"` to match only directories with "project" in the name. If the output looks correct, you could add `-delete` to have `find` remove the them.

With Bash and `shopt -s extglob` in effect, you could also use

```
echo rm -r !(*edit*)/
```

where the trailing slash would have it match only directories and `echo` just prints the command, instead of running it.

Comment: Thank you, this did exactly what I needed. Just had to replace `-delete` with `-exec rm -rv {} +` as the directories were not empty

Comment: @Den, ah yes of course `-delete` doesn't recurse, sorry.